# Using comparison operators on packageVersion

Tags: r

I'm writing some code for an R package that needs to compare the current package version to a record of the package version when it created a file. Basically, if the file was created by an old version of the package, it needs to check for changes to the file format. What I've got now is:

```
file_version<-get_file_version() # evals to a numeric like 100 or 302
pkg_version<-as.numeric(paste0(unlist(packageVersion('my.package')), collapse=""))

if (file_version < pkg_version) upgrade_fileformat() # checks and performs updates
```

So, this will work, but it seems like there should be a cleaner way to do this without the function sandwich to assign to the pkg_version variable. Does anyone know a nicer way to do the comparison I've described?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of recording a number, recording `packageVersion("my.package")` and then when reading coerce to `package_version()` so that the comparison operators work as expected.

```
ver <- as.numeric_version("3.10.1")
ver < "3.11"
# [1] TRUE
ver > "3"
# [1] TRUE
```